# Where is my internet speed slowing down?

Tags: networking, speed

I got a 300/300 Fiber internet connection - but running a speedtest, i only can max on just below 100/100.. How can I find out where the speed is going, can I check or see if its my router or my pc, or what it is. How can I get all 300/300 into my pc?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you only have 10/100 MB Lan ports.  can you confirm you have 10/100/1000 MB LAN ports?

Comment: I'd be agreeing with @Ramhound. It sounds like the NIC you are using is a 10/100Mbps NIC, and not the 10/100/1000Mbps port,

Comment: The connection could possibly be provisioned wrong by your isp/carrier. (Or  problems along the line somewhere).   If the modem and router are separate, I always eliminate the router for testing and plug one known good laptop directly into the modem and test.  If you can't get your speed that way then call your isp/carrier for service on the line. If you do get speed try adding things like the router back in until you find the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

The cause can be a lot of things.
As said in comments, simply your computer/router can't use it or your carrier set it wrong.
Try what @Tyson said, but if it doesn't work then call back your carrier if they're using router on their own.  mean i saw some, whose used routers/switches outside of the client's home. it's the least possible but can be.